# Where can I find a singular to plural converter?

Tags: wording, text-editor

Can anyone please help me find an ONLINE singular to plural (and visa versa) converter that will convert a list of words at once? I've found plenty that do one word at a time.

There are so many online text/word manipulaters out there, I'm surprised that I can't find one for singular and plural conversations.

Comment: I think mass conversion must be pretty niche... Do you have enough scripting knowledge to automate your list using a one-at-a-time service?

Comment: Technically, yes I can write a script that would do this while following the rules, however, there are words that have no rules that my code wouldn't work on. For example, tooth\teeth, child\children, etc.

Comment: I don't mean a script to convert them yourself — I mean a script to automate entering the words in one of the services you found.

Comment: Yes, I guess I can do this with AHK or something.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because its about a resource, not interface design.

Answer (score 1):

Found .NET PluralizationServices and Humanizer: https://github.com/Humanizr/Humanizer/blob/main/readme.md#pluralize.